# how to get data havin realtion on same table on same field without repeating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables named T1, T2, T3.

T1 has relation with T3 on field `Id`, same way T2 has relation with T3 on field `Id`. I want of all 3 which are matched.

Example:

**T1**

```
Id     otId 
-----------
1       5
2       6
3       7
```

**T2**

```
ID       pmId
-------------
1         1
2         3
3         4
```

**T3**

```
ID   ITEM       FORMFLAG
-------------------------
1     C          PM
3     DC         PM
4     OT         PM
5     DI         OT
6     PU         OT
7     D          OT
```

I want

```
ID       OT     PM
------------------
1        DI     OT
2        PU     C
3        D      DC
```

Comment: Could you please make in tabular format and then share

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT T1.id AS `ID`, T1.otId AS `OT`, T2.pm AS `PM`
FROM T1, T2, T3
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
  AND T1.id = T3.id;
```

Comment: there is no relation between t1 and t2. t1 have relation with t3 and t2 have relation with t3

Comment: if `t1` has relation with `t3` and `t3` with `t2`, dosen't that mean that `t1` has relation with `t2`? (transitivity)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Joins . Try this.

```
SELECT 
      TAB3.ID
     ,TAB3.ITEM AS OT
     ,TAB3.FORMFLAG AS PM
FROM
     T1 TAB1
INNER JOIN 
     T3 TAB3
ON
     TAB1.ID = TAB3.ID
INNER JOIN
     T2 TAB2
ON
     TAB3.ID = TAB2.ID
```